# python str.replace not getting arguments

Tags: python, sorting, arguments

I'm sorting a list using the key= function, i'm sorting a list of song titles written in LaTeX.

```
songs = sorted(songs, key=str.replace('$\lambda$','lambda'))
```

The problem is that when the function runs it says: "TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (got one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your key parameter should be a callable. You are sending a string now, this is the error.

You could try this:

```
songs = sorted(songs, key=lambda s: s.replace('$\lambda$','lambda'))
```

And for in-place sorting

```
songs.sort(key=lambda s: s.replace('$\lambda$','lambda'))
```

Comment: Or use `partial` from `functools` which is faster but requires an import.